# ckeditor5 autolink after setData?

Tags: hyperlink, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have activated the plugin AutoLink in ckeditor5. If i enter a URL, the URL becomes automatically a link, what is the expected behavior. However, if I load data from within a PHP script and use editor.setData(php.response), a URL is not autolinked. Is there a way to convert such links after insert data with setData() function?